# Query rows in the last seven days in android with room

Tags: android, sqlite, android-room

I'm trying to get items from my sqlite datebase using android room. I have an app that keeps track of a dog's potty events.

my DAO looks like

```
 @Query("SELECT * FROM potty_events_table ORDER BY datetime DESC")
fun getPottyEvents(): LiveData<List<PottyEventModel>>

@Query("SELECT * FROM potty_events_table WHERE datetime >= DATE('now', '-7 day')")
fun getPottyEventsFromLastWeek(): LiveData<List<PottyEventModel>>
```

the get potty events works fine but not the  one from last week. I also use the following converters. WHen I try to call my getPottyEventsFromLastWeek I get an empty array.

```
 @TypeConverter
fun fromTimestamp(value: Long): Calendar? {
    return value.let {
        val c = Calendar.getInstance()
        c.timeInMillis = it
        c
    }
}

@TypeConverter
fun calendarToTimestamp(calendar: Calendar?): Long? {
    return calendar?.timeInMillis
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your app API level is over 26 you can use the DateTimeFormatter and save the time in the database as a string.

So your converter looks like

```
private DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME;

@TypeConverter
public OffsetDateTime toOffsetDateTime(String string) {
    return formatter.parse(string, OffsetDateTime::from);
}

@TypeConverter
public String fromOffsetDatetime(OffsetDateTime offsetDateTime) {
    return offsetDateTime.format(formatter);
}
```

I used that because it transfers well when across multiple timezones

which then your `DOA` would change slightly to be

```
 @Query("SELECT * FROM potty_events_table ORDER BY datetime(<example>)")
 fun getPottyEvents(): LiveData<List<PottyEventModel>>
```

Just replace `<example>` with the column name that has the string list

Comment: Ah I'm working with API 21+. But I don't have an issue getting the events, I have an issue with getting events from a specific date. 

This worked for me for now 

`@Query("SELECT * FROM potty_events_table WHERE datetime >= (1000 * strftime('%s', datetime('now', '-7 day')))")`

I guess I thought the type converter would convert my date field in the query.